# Request large JSON in ORACLE UTL.HTTP

Tags: json, oracle, rest, web-services

I have a simple script to consume a Rest web service, it works fine, but when the answer exceeds 2000 characters, the select response is cut and the information is lost, so I need a way to keep all the data to insert them into tables later.

this is my script

```
WITH JSON AS
(
SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1') DOC FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  POSTID,
  ID,
  NAME,
  EMAIL,
  BODY
  FROM JSON_TABLE
  (
    (SELECT DOC FROM JSON),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS
           (
           POSTID PATH '$.postId',
           ID PATH '$.id',
           NAME PATH '$.name',
           EMAIL PATH '$.email',
           BODY PATH '$.body'
           )
  )
```

with this URL it works fine : 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1' (less than 2000chars)

with this larger one, the problem appears: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments' (more than 2000chars)

TY

Comment: There is a documented limitation when querying large JSON payloads. What version of Oracle are you using? Do you have APEX installed?

Comment: UTL_HTTP.REQUEST [only returns 2000 characters](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS71076). You'll need to load the response into a clob to use it in your query; you can either write your own function, or use [APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REQUEST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI1950) if you have APEX installed.

Comment: Oracle 12c, I'm not using APEX cos i want to make this as simple as possible.

Comment: Your other option is using Java. That was my solution when trying to work with very large JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the response and add the pieces to a CLOB, like so.

```
  --
  -- Make the HTTP request
  --
  v_url := 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1';
  dbms_output.put_line('URL sent: '||v_url);
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url => v_url);
  utl_http.set_header(r => req, name => 'User-Agent', value => 'Mozilla/4.0');

  --
  -- Loop through the response pieces
  --
  resp := utl_http.get_response(req);
  while not(eob)
  loop
     Begin
        utl_http.read_text(resp, string, 32766);
        --dbms_output.put_line(string);
        --
        -- Add the response pieces to a clob
        --
        data_clob := data_clob || string;
     Exception
        when utl_http.end_of_body then
           eob := true;
     End;
  end loop;
  utl_http.end_response(resp);

  --
  -- Convert to JSON
  --
  json_obj := json(data_clob);
```